# Can't I reach Amazon EC2 instance via my public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

The server works fine in my Amazon instance. But, when I use my browser I Can't,reach Amazon EC2 instance via my public IP.
Ping also does not work.

Any reason for that?

Comment: Check the Security Group [ Port 80 is opened to public - 0.0.0.0/0 ] and firewall rule is enabled for PORT 80. To enable ping you need add ICMP to the SG rules.

Comment: It gives another error [#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 327680 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
]

Comment: Can try resizing the instance little bigger. I believe you are using t1.micro just push it up to m1.small and see if you are still getting the same error

Comment: I think this is not a memory a problem.this is operating system memory problem.Am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check for the ports open to the destination
- check for the service if started
- check for internet connectivity- with NAT or External ip address
- check for internet gateways...ping 4.2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and was not able to access my website using the Public DNS. I added a new inbound firewall rule (in the EC2 instance) to open port 80 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether any web service is running on port 80 or not.

Comment: I checked it. Port 80 is open.

Comment: Ok Dheeraj,thanks for the quick response.i'll check it.